# Persisting state across tables on event change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table of schedules that is rendered by a dropdown. Each schedule can then be marked for export via a slider, this will store the schedule id in `scheduleIdsToExport` and show that schedule in the export table.

But if I change the `Select Query` dropdown, which renders more schedules specific to that query, the schedules marked for export from the previous query disappear from the table. I want the schedules marked for export to persist in the table no matter what query is selected from the dropdown.

So I'm thinking I need to have something in my `slider` function to update state with the all the schedule objects marked for export and have them persist in the exported table. I'm not exactly sure how to go about storing all the schedules to keep them in the exported table and have the `scheduleIdsToExport` array also keep the `id`'s of each schedule

```
  slider = ({ id, isExported }) => {
    if (isExported === true) {
      this.setState(
        {
          scheduleIdsToExport: [id, ...this.state.scheduleIdsToExport]
        },
        () => {
          console.log(this.state.scheduleIdsToExport);
        }
      );
    } else {
      const newArray = this.state.scheduleIdsToExport.filter(
        storedId => storedId !== id
      );
      this.setState(
        {
          scheduleIdsToExport: newArray
        },
        () => {
          console.log(this.state.scheduleIdsToExport);
        }
      );
    }
  };
```

The sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mo31vvkmn8) will provide further explanation on what is happening.

Comment: What do you want to have happen if an schedule from a different query that was selected to be exported is unselected while in a different query?

Comment: In theory the `id` of the schedule should be removed from the `scheduleIdsToExport` while also removing the schedule from the export table.

Comment: @nebuler do you have an idea of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wnnj3kmmzw).

In essence, it does not work in your example because of the following:

```
schedules
    .filter(schedule =>
        scheduleIdsToExport.includes(Number(schedule.id))
    )
    .map(schedule => {
        return (
            <Table.Row>
                ...
            </Table.Row>
        );
     })
```

The value of `schedules` is always set to the current *query*, hence you end up showing schedules to export for the current query only.

A solution that changes very little of your code is to ditch `scheduleIdsToExport` altogether, and use `schedulesToExport` instead. Initially, we'll set `schedulesToExport` to an empty
object; we'll add *schedules* to it (keyed by schedule id) every time a schedule is selected - we'll delete schedules in the same way every time a schedule is unselected.

```
class App extends React.Component {

    // ...

    slider = ({ id, isExported }) => {
        const obj = this.state.schedules.find(s => Number(s.id) === Number(id));
        if (isExported === true) {
            this.setState({
                schedulesToExport: {
                    ...this.state.schedulesToExport,
                    [id]: {
                        ...obj
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            const newSchedulesToExport = this.state.schedulesToExport;
            delete newSchedulesToExport[id];
            this.setState({
                schedulesToExport: newSchedulesToExport
            });
        }
    };

    // ...
}
```

You would then render the schedules to export as follows:

```
Object.keys(schedulesToExport).map(key => {
    const schedule = schedulesToExport[key];
    return (
        <Table.Row>
            ...
        </Table.Row>
     );
 })
```

Again, see more details in sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wnnj3kmmzw).

Comment: Thank you providing the sandbox in addition. One remark, when the schedule is selected for export, the `id` of that schedule should be added to `schedulesIdsToExport` array. Im my original linked sandbox, they are being added to the array correctly, but if the slider is deselected the `id` of the schedule is not removed from the array.

Comment: @DJ2 you can get the ids of schedules to export by doing `Object.keys(this.state. schedulesToExport)`. Like I said, I would just ditch `schedulesIdsToExport` altogether and solely use `schedulesToExport`. You can tweak a few other things if you want to keep it, but the solution I provided changes very little of your existing code.  Let me know if that makes sense!

Comment: In render, yes, this `Object.keys(this.state. schedulesToExport)` will get the `id`'s but I need to have them added/removed properly in state inside of an array.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Instead of calling `this.state.schedulesIdsToExport`, call `Object.keys(this.state.schedulesToExport)`. The same information is in the state, just in a different "format". You can still use `schedulesIdsToExport` (you'll have to add it back), but it would be redundant. Also, note that if you want to use the updated state, you'll have to access it in a callback passed to `this.setState`. For example, `this.setState({ someProp }, () => console.log('do something here'))`.

Comment: Is there anything that doesn't work as expected in the sandbox I provided?

Comment: In my `exportSchedules` function I'm sending `data: JSON.stringify({
          scheduleIds: scheduleIdsToExport
        })` which is an array of the `id`'s that were selected for export, for exmaple: `{"scheduleIds":[703] }`
So you're saying I can just do this now, `scheduleIds: Object.keys(schedulesToExport)` ?. That works

Answer (score 4):

This is just chaotic!

**The problem :** Keep track from multiples list of items(schedules) that will eventually be added to another list `schedulesToExport`

**The Solution :**

- Create a parent component that reflects the previously described state

  ```
  class Container extends Component{
      state ={
          querys :[
              ['foo','lore ipsum','it\'s never lupus'],
              ['bar','ipsumlorem', 'take the canolli']
          ],
          selectedQuery : 0,
          schedulesToExport : []
     }
  }
  ```

Now we have a list of lists, that can be interpreted as a list of querys containing a list of schedules

- Render a `select` element to reflect each query:

  ```
  render(){
    const { querys, selectedQuery } = this.state
    const options = querys.map((_, index) => (<option value={index}> Query: {index + 1}</option>))
    return(
      <div>
        <select onChange={this.selectQuery}>
          {options}
        </select>
        {
          querys[selectedQuery].map(schedule => (
            <button onClick={() => this.selectSchedule(index)}> Schedule: {schedule} </button>
          ))
        }
     </div>
   )
  }
  ```

What's happening? We are just rendering the selected query by it's index and showing all it's respective schedules.

- Implement the `selectQuery` and `selectSchedule` methods which will add the selected schedule in the list to export:

  ```
  selectQuery = e => this.setState({selectedQuery : e.target.value})

  selectSchedule = index => {
    const { selectedQuery } = this.state
    const selected  = this.state.querys[selectedQuery][index]
    this.setState({ 
      schedulesToExport: this.state.schedulesToExport.concat(selected) 
    })
  }
  ```

That's it, now you a have a list of querys being displayed conditionally rendered `selectedQuery` props is just a index, but could be a property's name. You only see schedules from the current selected query, so when you click on schedule we just return it's index, and the `state.querys[selectedQuery][index]` will be your selected schedule, that is securely store in the state on a separated list.

Comment: Any chance you can edit the sandbox with these changes? I'm not sure how the container and the query state works in

Comment: I guess my question is what is the previously described state in the Container class?

Comment: It's a list of  queries each containing another list of schedules, in this case the schedules are just random strings, in reality they would be objects

Comment: Can you edit the sandbox? I'm having trouble implementing your proposed solution

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding your solution. The parent component is rendering a completely new selection and it is visually not making sense

Comment: I'm sorry,  extremely busy days, as soon as I can I will update the example